# Typeahead Autocomplete AJAX

Tags: jquery, ajax, twitter-bootstrap, typeahead

I'm trying to fill up the bootstrap autocomplete(Typeahead) list with data provided by an external Web-service, in this case "Wunderground Weather", but it's not working.

It's returnin an error saying "hasOwnProperty".

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

 <script src="bootstrap-typeahead.js"></script>
```

HTML

```
<div class="col-md-12">
    <h1>Search Dynamic Autocomplete using Bootstrap Typeahead JS</h1>   
    <input class="typeahead form-control"  type="text">
</div>
```

JQuery

```
$(".typeahead").typeahead({
   source: function (query,process) {
                return process(autoCompleteWunderGround(query))
            }
});


function autoCompleteWunderGround(query){
    var results = []
    $.ajax({
        url : "http://autocomplete.wunderground.com/aq?query=query",
        dataType : "jsonp",
        jsonp : "cb",
        data : {
        "query" : query,
        "format" : "JSON",
        },
        success : function(data) {
            $.each( data.RESULTS, function( index, value ){
                results.push(value.name) 
            })
        }
    });

    return results;

}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is in the return of the function autoCompleteWunderGround(). Ajax is asynchronous so the return of the function is executet before the success. The array results it's never filled.
You can try with a callback function.

Comment: What do you mean? Can you provide an example? Thanks